# Find wavelet transform coefficients in L1 norm

Tags: wavelet-analysis, discrete

For my masters task I have to perform a Haar wavelet transform using an L1 norm. But *Mathematica*'s built-in wavelet library can work only with L2 norm space.  I tried to do this:

```
haarBasic[t_] := If[0 <= t <= 0.5, 1, If[0.5 <= t <= 1, -1, 0]]
haarBasic[t_] := If[0 <= t <= 0.5, 1, If[0.5 <= t <= 1, -1, 0]]


haarCoeffs[list_List, N_] := 
    Module[{coeffs = Table[c[i][j], {i, N}, {j, 2^i - 1}], minimazed},
      minimazed = NMinimize[
          Sum[Abs[Sum[
             coeffs[[i, j]] haarBasisFunc[t, i, j], {i, N}, {j, 
                2^i - 1}] - list[[t]]], {t, Length@list}], coeffs];
          Print[minimazed[[1]]];
          coeffs /. minimazed[[2]]
   ];
```

but it does not work.  I have syntax problems and understanding problem. Because all books what I have seen (Daubechies, for example) has focused on the L2 norm spaces.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the definition of haarBasisFunc?

Comment: `haarBasisFunc[t_, k_, n_] := 2^(k/2) haarBasic[2^k t - n];`
Sorry, I failed with copy-paste.